# Singular followed by plural list

Tags: grammatical-number, lists

Which is correct?

1. Equipment is gloves and glasses.
2. Equipment are gloves and glasses.

I'm editing a book, and this translation I'm working with has been confirmed by the client, so terms cannot be changed or added.

Comment: "Equipment **consists of** gloves and glasses."

Comment: *Equipment* is a mass noun.

Comment: Ok, but it cannot be changed. I'm editting a book, and this translation I'm working with has been confirmed by the client, terms cannot be changed or added. But I got mixed up with is/are

Comment: *editing* has a single-*t* not double-*t* -- Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: Sorry, been up all night working, misspelled

Answer (score 2):

As [@Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233355/singular-followed-by-plural-list#comment501615_233355) noted, the word *equipment* is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun), meaning that it refers to a quantity of something as a discrete, undifferentiated entity.  Singular verb forms are used with mass nouns, so you should "is" rather than "are" in this case.

But it's an awkward sentence either way.  It would be more natural to use some other verb than "to be" to relate the two parts of the sentence:

> The equipment consists of gloves and glasses.